# Assign variables based on all list choices

Tags: 2010

My apologies as I'm certain this has been asked and answered, but I don't know how to phrase my question well as this is my first sharepoint project. I'm using SPD2010 and infopath2013

I want to assign variables in a workflow based on one of the 12 choices in a list category.

Is there a way to do this outside of a series of if statements?

Some more detail:

The workflow is running and waiting for the field to change from "Default" which occurs at various points in my main workflow

At that point I want to assign variables based on what it changed to:

> If emailtype = approved then assign variable to x
>
> If emailtype = rejected then assign variable to y

etc, etc.

Once the variables are assigned, I then check for which groups are  involved and email them using the variable data in the message field (this is so that I can get this workflow to run at the various points in the main workflow to message this group)

> If department1 = yes then email xxxx
>
> If department2 = yes then email yyyy

etc, through the dozen departments I have

After all is sent, I reassign the email type back to "Default" to reset the wait.

> set emailtype = Deafult

Any thoughts/advice/answers are truly appreciated.

Thanks,

Todd